# awk count and sum based on slab:

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to extract all the lines from first file (GunZip *.gz i.e  Input.csv.gz), if the first file 4th field is falls within a range of 
Second file (Slab.csv) first field (Start Range) and second field (End Range) then populate Slab wise count of rows and sum of 4th and 5th field of first file.

Input.csv.gz (GunZip)

```
Desc,Date,Zone,Duration,Calls
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,450,3
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,642,3
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,0,0
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,205,3
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,98,1
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,455,1
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,120,1
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,0,0
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,193,1
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,0,0
AB,01-06-2014,XYZ,161,2
```

Slab.csv

```
StartRange,EndRange
0,0
1,10
11,100
101,200
201,300
301,400
401,500
501,10000
```

Expected Output:

```
StartRange,EndRange,Count,Sum-4,Sum-5
0,0,3,0,0
1,10,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound
11,100,1,98,1
101,200,3,474,4
201,300,1,205,3
301,400,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound
401,500,2,905,4
501,10000,1,642,3
```

I am using below two commands to get the above output , expect "NotFound"cases .

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{s[NR]=$1;e[NR]=$2;c[NR]=$0;n++;next} {for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if($4>=s[i]&&$4<=e[i]) {print $0,","c[i];break}}' Slab.csv <(gzip -dc Input.csv.gz) >Op_step1.csv
cat Op_step1.csv | awk -F, '{key=$6","$7;++a[key];b[key]=b[key]+$4;c[key]=c[key]+$5} END{for(i in a)print i","a[i]","b[i]","c[i]}' >Op_step2.csv
```

Op_step2.csv

```
101,200,3,474,4
501,10000,1,642,3
0,0,3,0,0
401,500,2,905,4
11,100,1,98,1
201,300,1,205,3
```

Any suggestions to make it one liner command to achieve the Expected Output , Don't have perl , python access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `awk` and `sort`:

```
awk '
BEGIN { 
    FS = OFS = SUBSEP = ",";
    print "StartRange,EndRange,Count,Sum-4,Sum-5" 
} 
FNR == 1 { next }
NR == FNR {
    ranges[$1,$2]++;
    next
}
{
    for (range in ranges) {
        split(range, tmp, SUBSEP); 
        if ($4 >= tmp[1] && $4 <= tmp[2]) {
            count[range]++;
            sum4[range]+=$4;
            sum5[range]+=$5; 
            next
        }
    }
}
END {
    for(range in ranges) 
        print range, (count[range]?count[range]:"NotFound"), (sum4[range]?sum4[range]:"NotFound"), (sum5[range]?sum5[range]:"NotFound") | "sort -t, -nk1,2"
}' slab input
StartRange,EndRange,Count,Sum-4,Sum-5
0,0,3,NotFound,NotFound
1,10,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound
11,100,1,98,1
101,200,3,474,4
201,300,1,205,3
301,400,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound
401,500,2,905,4
501,10000,1,642,3
```

- Set the Input, Output Field Separators and `SUBSEP` to `,`. Print the Header line.
- If it is the first line skip it.
- Load the entire `slab.txt` in to an array called `ranges`.
- For every range in the `ranges` array, split the field to get start and end range. If the 4th column is in the range, increment the count array and add the value to `sum4` and `sum5` array appropriately.
- In the `END` block, iterate through the ranges and print them.
- Pipe the output to `sort` to get the output in order.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option using `perl` which takes benefits of creating multi-dimensional arrays and hashes.

```
perl -F, -lane'
BEGIN {
    $x = pop; 
    ## Create array of arrays from start and end ranges
    ## $range = ( [0,0] , [1,10] ... )
    (undef, @range)= map { chomp; [split /,/] } <>; 
    @ARGV = $x;
}
## Skip the first line
next if $. ==1; 
## Create hash of hash
## $line = '[0,0]' => { "count" => counts , "sum4" => sum_of_col4 , "sum5" => sum_of_col5 }
for (@range) { 
  if ($F[3] >= $_->[0] && $F[3] <= $_->[1]) { 
    $line{"@$_"}{"count"}++; 
    $line{"@$_"}{"sum4"} +=$F[3]; 
    $line{"@$_"}{"sum5"} +=$F[4];
  } 
} 
}{ 
  print "StartRange,EndRange,Count,Sum-4,Sum-5"; 
  print join ",", @$_, 
  $line{"@$_"}{"count"} //"NotFound",  
  $line{"@$_"}{"sum4"}  //"NotFound", 
  $line{"@$_"}{"sum5"}  //"NotFound" 
    for @range
' slab input
StartRange,EndRange,Count,Sum-4,Sum-5
0,0,3,0,0
1,10,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound
11,100,1,98,1
101,200,3,474,4
201,300,1,205,3
301,400,NotFound,NotFound,NotFound
401,500,2,905,4
501,10000,1,642,3
```

Comment: Thanks so much @mpapec. Awesome feedback. The `//` didn't seem to work on my ancient `perl` at work (5.8.8). Will test it out at home. Thanks so much .. appreciate it `:)`.

Comment: Check `plenv`, you can have v5.20 or any other in your home folder. https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv

Comment: Thanks @mpapec for the link. I had struggled with local::lib previously. Will try this out next week.