# space delimited file handling

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have insider transactions of a company in a space delimited file. Sample data looks like the following:

```
1 Gilliland Michael S January 2,2013 20,000 19
2 Still George J Jr January 2,2013 20,000 19
3 Bishkin S. James February 1,2013 150,000 21
4 Mellin Mark P May 28,2013 238,000 25.26
```

Col1 is Serial# that I dont need to print
Col2 is the name of the person who did trades. This column is not consistent. It has first name and second name and middle initial and for some insiders salutations as well (Mr, Dr. Jr etc)
col3 is the date format Month Day,Year
col4 is the number of shares traded
col5 is the price at which shares were purchased or sold.

I need you guys help to print each column value separately. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have spaces inside of fields and your columns are space-delimited, you won't be able to get a *clean* solution. Ideally you want to be able to extract your data in `tsv` format. Also, it is customary to show what you have tried before soliciting assistance on StackOverflow.

Comment: You mean you want a command that will print the names, another command that will print the dates, and so on?

Comment: Do you have any control over how the data looks?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. This is how we are receiving the data from the source.

Comment: Are you using AWK to try to get the values? I have no experience with it, so I was wondering if you know if it has regex capabilities? That might be your only hope.

Comment: @Beta, Yes. I want to print the values of col2 to col5.

Comment: @Zack, why would you need regex support for this? All one needs to do is count the number of space-delimited fields and subtract, since there's only a single variable-width field; it's only if there were more than one that this would be error-prone. (Also, regexes are also available in native bash; see the `=~` operator within `[[ ]]`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy more than one *what* would make *what* error prone? op said that the name can contain salutations which throws off the possible number of spaces used to delineate the "fields". You can see the difference between line 1 and line 2 that line 1 uses 7 spaces, and line 2 uses 8 spaces because of the included `Jr` salutation.

Comment: @Zack, more than one variable-length field. Since we have exactly one variable-length field, and all the others are fixed-length (measured, in this case, by whitespace-separated columns), it's trivial to calculate that variable-length field's width.

Comment: Re-read your comment and it makes sense now. My reading comprehension must have been suffering the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the data separated using `awk`

```
awk '{c1=$1;c5=$NF;c4=$(NF-1);c3=$(NF-3)FS$(NF-2);$1=$NF=$(NF-1)=$(NF-2)=$(NF-3)="";gsub(/^ | *$/,"");c2=$0;print c1"|"c2"|"c3"|"c4"|"c5}' file
1|Gilliland Michael S|January 2,2013|20,000|19
2|Still George J Jr|January 2,2013|20,000|19
3|Bishkin S. James|February 1,2013|150,000|21
4|Mellin Mark P|May 28,2013|238,000|25.26
```

You know have your data in variable `c1` to `c5`

Or better displayed here:

```
awk '{c1=$1;c5=$NF;c4=$(NF-1);c3=$(NF-3)FS$(NF-2);$1=$NF=$(NF-1)=$(NF-2)=$(NF-3)="";gsub(/^ | *$/,"");c2=$0;print c1"|"c2"|"c3"|"c4"|"c5}' file | column -t -s "|"
1  Gilliland Michael S  January 2,2013   20,000   19
2  Still George J Jr    January 2,2013   20,000   19
3  Bishkin S. James     February 1,2013  150,000  21
4  Mellin Mark P        May 28,2013      238,000  25.26
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jotne. You'r amazing. I spent few hours on this before I posted the question here.

Answer (score 1):

Count the total number of fields read; the difference between that and the number of non-name fields gives you the width of the name.

```
#!/bin/bash
# uses bash features, so needs a /bin/bash shebang, not /bin/sh

# read all fields into an array
while read -r -a fields; do

  # calculate name width assuming 5 non-name fields
  name_width=$(( ${#fields[@]} - 5 ))
  cur_field=0

  # read initial serial number
  ser_id=${fields[cur_field]}; (( ++cur_field ))

  # read name
  name=''
  for ((i=0; i<name_width; i++)); do
    name+=" ${fields[cur_field]}"; (( ++cur_field ))
  done
  name=${name# } # trim leading space

  # date spans two fields due to containing a space
  date=${fields[cur_field]}; (( ++cur_field ))
  date+=" ${fields[cur_field]}"; (( ++cur_field ))

  # final fields are one span each
  num_shares=${fields[cur_field]}; (( ++cur_field ))
  price=${fields[cur_field]}; (( ++cur_field ))

  # print in newline-delimited form
  printf '%s\n' "$ser_id" "$name" "$date" "$num_shares" "$price" ""
done
```

Run as follows (if you saved the script as `process`):

```
./process <input.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: WoW! Charles you did it the way I never thought of doing it. I was trying with sed and awk. I'm a database guy and trying to load data in the database. Thanks for the quick reply but I think I would go for awk. I tried both solutions provided by you and Jotne. I think I'll go with awk. Excellent stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little easier in `perl`.

```
perl -lane '
    @date = splice @F, -4, 2;
    @left = splice @F, -2, 2;
    splice @F, 0, 1;
    print join "|", "@F", "@date", @left
' file
Gilliland Michael S|January 2,2013|20,000|19
Still George J Jr|January 2,2013|20,000|19
Bishkin S. James|February 1,2013|150,000|21
Mellin Mark P|May 28,2013|238,000|25.26
```

You can change the delimiter in the `join` as per your requirement.

Comment: +1; I think this might be the most readable solution here (and am astonished at the words coming out of my mouth... readable perl, will wonders never cease?)

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. I appreciate your vote of confidence. As the wise man once said _Perl is designed to give you several ways to do anything, so consider picking the most readable one._ I'll try to follow it as much as I can. (No [promises](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24455656/970195) though) `;)`